# Отправить ping и отследить, доступен узел или нет

Tags: c++

Как отправить пинг и проверить условие доступен узел или нет.

```
 if (ping 1.3.4.5) {
 } 
 else
 {
 }
```

Comment: Последний ответ: [тык](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697292/pinging-from-a-c-c-program)

Comment: int x = system("ping 8.8.8.8  > null 2>&1");
if (x==0){

}else{

}